# Has any one used OrientDB with a ASP.Net website

Tags: asp.net, orientdb

I am looking to move away from neo4j mainly because of the price which is so steep and we assumed it to be an opensource all the time. Upward of $30K/year is not something we can afford for a database, I guess we should have done our homework well.

Any ways Neo4j has an actively maintained neo4jClient for .Net which was the primary criteria for us to select that database, only other option that comes close is **OrientDB**  which also has a rest endpoint that we can consume. But has only few c# clients that I can find on the net. Also out of these none have been updated for almost 2-3 years.

So I was wondering if any one has used OrientDB in a real world project and have seen a dependable c# client that can be used with this database.

Also any sample that shows some of the best practices on working with OrientDB and ASP.Net will be really helpful.

Regards
Kiran

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am on the OrientDB Team. I have to apologize, we have not done a good job of communicating the various language APIs on our website. This will be improved.

For now, you can see: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Programming-Language-Bindings.

I know I have seen activity around the .NET connector recently. We are have a concerted focus on all of these libraries and continued maintenance of them. Again, as you mentioned, the REST API is always there as well.

Best wishes,

Greg McCarvell
Orient Technologies
info@orientechnologies.com

Answer (score 0):

The .NET driver I can suggest is:

https://github.com/workshare/OrientDB-NET.binary

It's actively updated.